# Reverse for 'restaurants_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Need help unable to rectify this error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /myrestaurants/
Reverse for 'restaurants_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myrestaurants/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'restaurants_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 495
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/vaibhav/Desktop/projects/myrecommendations',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
Server time:    Fri, 2 Feb 2018 02:02:23 +0000
```

My index.html looks like this :

```
{% block content %}
        <nav class="nav nav-bar">
            <div class="pull-right" style="padding: 20px;">
                {% if user.is_anonymous %}
                    <a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Sign In</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Sign Out</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="app-font">Welcome to Food-orders</h1>
            <form method="GET" class="form-inline" action="{% url 'restaurants_list' %}">
                <input type="text" id="locator" class="form-control">
                {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                    {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-search" %} SEARCH FOR RESTAURANTS
                </button>
                {% endbuttons %}
            </form>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My myrestaurants/urls.py looks like this :

```
from django.utils import timezone

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView

import myrestaurants
from myrestaurants import views
from myrestaurants.forms import RestaurantForm, DishForm
from myrestaurants.models import Restaurant, Dish
from myrestaurants.views import RestaurantDetail, RestaurantCreate, DishCreate, RestaurantUpdate, DishUpdate

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home-page'),
    #url(r'^list/$', views.RestaurantListView.as_view(), name='restaurant-list'),
    # List latest 5 restaurants: /myrestaurants/
    url(r'^myrestaurants/$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Restaurant.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('date')[:8],
            context_object_name='latest_restaurant_list',
            template_name='myrestaurants/restaurant_list.html'),
        name='restaurant_list'),

    # Restaurant details, ex.: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        RestaurantDetail.as_view(),
        name='restaurant_detail'),

    # Restaurant dish details, ex: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/dishes/1/
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pkr>\d+)/dishes/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Dish,
            template_name='myrestaurants/dish_detail.html'),
        name='dish_detail'),

    # Create a restaurant, /myrestaurants/restaurants/create/
    url(r'^restaurants/create/$',
        RestaurantCreate.as_view(),
        name='restaurant_create'),

    # Edit restaurant details, ex.: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/edit/
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
        RestaurantUpdate.as_view(),
        name='restaurant_edit'),

    # Create a restaurant dish, ex.: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/dishes/create/
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\d+)/dishes/create/$',
        DishCreate.as_view(),
        name='dish_create'),

    # Edit restaurant dish details, ex.: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/dishes/1/edit/
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pkr>\d+)/dishes/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
        DishUpdate.as_view(),
        name='dish_edit'),

    # Create a restaurant review, ex.: /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/reviews/create/
    # Unlike the previous patterns, this one is implemented using a method view instead of a class view
    url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\d+)/reviews/create/$',
        myrestaurants.views.review,
        name='review_create'),
]
```

My myrecommendations/urls.py looks like this :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from myrestaurants import urls as restaurants_urls


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='myrestaurants', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='restaurant_list', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^myrestaurants/', include('myrestaurants.urls', namespace="myrestaurants")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
#if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, })
]
```

My views.py looks like this :

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from myrestaurants.forms import DishForm, RestaurantForm
from myrestaurants.models import Restaurant, RestaurantReview, Dish

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "myrestaurants/index.html"

class RestaurantDetail(DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'myrestaurants/restaurant_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['RATING_CHOICES'] = RestaurantReview.RATING_CHOICES
        return context


class RestaurantCreate(CreateView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'myrestaurants/form.html'
    form_class = RestaurantForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("myrestaurants:restaurant_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        messages.success(self.request, '"%s"vaibhav' % name)
        return super(RestaurantCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

After trying so hard unable to find out the mistake and proper solution of this error.Need help badly.Thanks in advance

Comment: Think carefully before using `permanent=True` in your `RedirectView` on the homepage. If it's permanent then it could cause problems if you ever decide to change it in future.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you called your url `restaurant_list` not `restaurants_list`

Use `myrestaurants:restaurant_list` instead of `restaurants_list` in your template, and all should be ok

`<form method="GET" class="form-inline" action="{% url 'myrestaurants:restaurant_list' %}">`

Comment: Good spot, but I think you need to add include the namespace as well, e.g. `'myrestaurants:restaurant_list'`.

Comment: Thanks Angel F for pointing out my stupid mistake and @Alasdair what you told is the proper solution of my problem.New to stackoverflow doesn't know how to upvote a comment but +100 for my side.

Comment: @Vaibhav Goyal I've updtaded muy answer, i didn't see they namespace, but you are rigth, if the namespace is setted, of Course, the best way is use namespace + urlname

Comment: @Angel F without namespace before url not worked for me I don't know why but still.Btw thanks for updating the answer